# Unable to add new windows phone portrait image (New App XAML Page)

Tags: windows-phone-7, visual-studio-2012

When I right click on the project node, and click "Add"->"New Item",
There is no option of a "Windows Phone Portrait Page" to add
instead only "XNA Game Studio" objects.
Do I need to re-install the WinPhone SDK?

Comment: did you create an XNA game app?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've probably just clicked on one of the sub-sections, try looking in a different new item section